# String size violation

Tags: java, database, jsp

I am trying to retrieve elements from database, using a while loop in a jsp page.

It is showing upto 3000 element correct but after that it shows a message,

> Encountered error for Custom Page FeatureRequest.jsp - Error is String
>   size violation; String size Limit: 30000; String size: 30018

Comment: Share the code of looping

Comment: please share your code